# python - sqllite - what is this object?0- subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

After got a cursor object as follow,

```
db = sqlite3.connect("froshims.db")
cur = db.cursor()
rows = cur.execute("select * from registrants")
```

I was able to print of table's content by either

1) fetch method

```
dd=rows.fetchone()
print(dd)
```

or
2) by for

```
for row in rows:
    print(f"{row} registered")
```

However, when i try to do so by simply doing print(rows[0]) it is not accessible.
I saw the error saying that rows is not subscriptable by itself but how i can read it by for method as such 2)? if its not subscriptable by itself method 2) should not readable like so isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Just for information you can loop over objects that are not subscriptable, (as you have noticed) and its not code breaking.

- For an object to be subscriptable it needs to implement a `__getitem__()` method. If this is missing you cant use the `x[i]` syntax.
- To loop over items in an object it needs the implement the `__iter__()` and `__next__()` methods. If any are missing you cant use the `for i in x:` syntax

In most cases if the iterable protocols are implemented the subscript ones are implemented as well. (vice versa)

There is a mention of both of the methods in the python docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)